# Why do HTTP loopback connections not work on my subdomains?

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, wordpress, loopback

I have a shared hosting account at Jumba running Linux kernel 2.6.9-103.ELsmp (don't know if that helps) with cpanel 1.0 (RC1).

I am using the WordPress plugin Backup Buddy, which requires HTTP loopback connections to monitor / complete backups.  This works fine on `memelab.com.au`, but doesn't work at any subdomain (e.g.: `staging.memelab.com.au`).

Is it possible to setup an A record or some such to remedy this?

I'm aware of a workaround, (setting `WP_ALTERNATE_CRON`) but I find this unsatisfactory due to the messy URLs.

[BackupBuddy:_Frequent_Support_Issues#HTTP_Loopback_Connections_Disabled](http://ithemes.com/codex/page/BackupBuddy:_Frequent_Support_Issues#HTTP_Loopback_Connections_Disabled)

---

Here is the reply from my host:

> …as main
>   domain have it's own separate DNS entry it have localhost entry which
>   helps for looback connections where as subdomains don't have separate
>   DNS zone, so it is not possible to create looback connections for it.

I have cpanel access to the 'advanced zone editor' - is there anything tricky I can do there? maybe `127.0.0.2`? (I remember reading that there were at least 8 available local IPs available on (some) Linuxes.)

---

All the A records point to the server IP, with the exception of `localhost.memelab.com.au` which points to `127.0.0.1`.

I've just tried entering a new A record: localhost.itours.memelab.com.au pointing to 127.0.0.2. I still get the warning in Backup Buddy that loopback is not active, and Cpanel won't let me enter 127.0.0.1 (guess it doesn't work like that!)

---

```
nslookup itours.memelab.com.au
Server:     203.88.112.33
Address:    203.88.112.33#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   itours.memelab.com.au
Address: 117.55.224.177
```

Comment: On the machine, what do the subdomains resolve to?  This could be a problem with virtual hosts, or it could be a problem with not listening, or it could be a problem with name resolution.

Comment: hmm.. not sure I can answer that, @FalconMomot! The subdomains are all subdirectories of the main domain - thanks for looking!

Comment: Assuming you have shell access to the server, you can simply use nslookup to determine the local resolution.

Comment: great tip, thanks.. but I have no idea what it means! I added the result to the post... 117.55.224.177 is the server IP for the main domain and all subs...

Comment: Is all of itours.memelab.com.au protected with basic HTTP authentication? If so that is probably why "Backup Buddy" isn't working.

Comment: just tried adding another localhost entry, detailed above...

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem on my VPS by allowing sub accounts to run the ping command.

http://ben.goodacre.name/tech/Ping:_icmp_open_socket:_Operation_not_permitted_(Linux)